# Use @EnvironmentObject with PresentationButton in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to pass data through an `@EnvironmentObject`, but it works only if I go to the next view through `NavigationButton`, however, I want to present the next view modally (`PresentationButton`)

```
struct ContentView : View {

     @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

     var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        VStack {
            // A button that writes to the environment settings
            Button(action: {
                self.settings.score += 1
            }) {
                Text("Increase Score")
            }
            NavigationButton(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Show Detail View")
            }
        }
      }
   }
}

struct DetailView: View {
     @EnvironmentObject var settings: UserSettings

     var body: some View {
     // A text view that reads from the environment settings
        VStack {
            Text("Score: \(settings.score)")        
        }
     }
 }
```

What I am trying to use :

```
 PresentationButton( Text("Show Detail View"), destination: DetailView())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try supplying the bindable object to the `DetailView` using `environmentObject`:

```
PresentationButton(Text("Show Detail View"), 
                   destination: DetailView().environmentObject(settings))
```

Comment: I tried and it works, but I want to present a couple of views from one to another, some of them use settings and some of them not, so, I don't want to transfer the settings manually like this, I think this is the purpose of @EnvironmentObject, otherwise I could use a normal var

Comment: @SorinLica in that case I think the use of a singleton wouldn't be a bad idea. By making sure it is used as an EnvironmentObject and the fact that the data flow is unidirectional means that some of the potentially bad side effects of using a singleton are eliminated. It is definitely something to keep in mind though.

Comment: @Fogmeister Interesting could you provide a code example?